# Extract block between characters and before date

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse the following file name and extract the bolded and italicized area:

00000_***12345678***_2023-10-30_AAA_bbb.pdf

An initial solution would be:

```
(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

And what I get is:

[image]

Looks nice but there is a catch. If I just duplicate my token, everything goes wrong.

[image]

So, for real, my question would be:

How can I extract the part between underlines and immediately before the date and nothing more?

Comment: Like this? `(?<=_)[^_\n]+(?=_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` https://regex101.com/r/UcBi9s/1 Or with a capture group `_([^_\n]+)_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` https://regex101.com/r/VaqX5i/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use lookarounds, you don't need the capture group. You can use a negated character class `[^` to prevent crossing the underscore in the match:

```
(?<=_)[^_\n]+(?=_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UcBi9s/1)

Or without lookarounds, using the capture group and match before and after it:

```
 _([^_\n]+)_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VaqX5i/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I saw your comment and tested it right away. It worked. @AymDev Your answer works fine too, please find my excuses because I can't mark them both as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your actuel RegEx seems to capture everything between the first underscore and the date. You could change it to capture everything before the date as long as there is no underscore inside:

```
([^_]+)(?=_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HXyfZp/1